# How to display 7 digit numbers in matlab list box

Tags: matlab

I have been tasked to fix bug in a matlab program written by other people and have an issue with displaying 7 digit serial numbers in a list box. I get the number from a database and the numbers get pulled but instead of for example having serial number 4800801 displayed in the listbox control, it is displayed in scientific notation.

Here is the code

```
statement = 'select product_serial_number from master_product where status = 109 order by product_serial_number ASC';
curs = exec(conn, statement);
curs = fetch(curs);

if strcmp(curs.Data,'No Data') == 0
    handles.matrix(1:length(cell2mat(curs.Data)),1) = cell2mat(curs.Data);
end

handles.BasePre2Data = curs.Data;
set(handles.ListBasePreBuild2,'String',handles.BasePre2Data);
r = cellfun(@isnumeric, curs.Data);

if mean(r) == 1
    set(handles.TextBoxBasePreBuild2Total,'String',num2str(length(handles.BasePre2Data)));
else
    set(handles.TextBoxBasePreBuild2Total,'String','0');
    handles.BasePre2Data = [];

end
```

I am new to matlab so I am not sure how to format the output to all 7 digit numbers.

Comment: I don't get which number in your code you are having trouble with. What if you use sprintf('%.0f',YourNumberHere) ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with list boxes in MATLAB. If you have some matrix `M`  that would you like to read as integers rather than floats/scientific notation, you can use `M_integer = cast(M,'uint32')`. I'm not sure where you would apply this in your code. Which variable represents the serial numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,i had to use cellfun and change the format to num2str

```
set(handles.ListBasePreBuild2,'String',cellfun(@num2str,handles.BasePre2Data,'UniformOutput',false));
```